# How can I dismiss the alertbox after clicking back button

Tags: android, dialog, kotlin, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have the activity in which calling the adapter class. In the adapter class, after clicking on item, dialog box is open. Now I am not able to figuring out to close this dialog box after clicking the back button.

Here is my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // fetching the required data
         // blogs is recyclerview
         blogs.setAdapter(new BlogAdapter(MainActivity.this,blogArrayList));
      }


@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //not printed
        Log.i("Back button pressed ","MainActivity");
   }

 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        //not printed
        Log.i("On key down ","Main Activity");
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
```

}

Adapter class

```
class BlogAdapter(var mcontext: Context, var post:ArrayList<Blog>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            openDialog(post.get(position),mcontext)
        }
}
 private fun  openDialog(post: Blog?,context:Context) {

        val layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.individual_blog, null)

        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppFullScreen_Dialog_Theme))

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView)

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            mView.title_blog.text = Html.fromHtml(post?.postTitle,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            mView.title_blog.text=Html.fromHtml(post?.postTitle)
        }


        val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
        alertDialog!!.show()

        alertDialogBuilder.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->

            Log.i("Set On Key Listener ","dialog")
            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                alertDialog.dismiss()
            }
            true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use **alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);** to make your dialog cancelable

Comment: why do you use two kinds of language. you should use just java or kotlin. for your need, you have to create interface and call it from Main. Then show Dialog. And you can make as you wish there.

Comment: Actually, the project is written in Java but I want to get my hand dirty by Kotlin. So the project is in two languages. For this case, First load the data using recycler view and adapter class. Then on touch, the item (recycler view item) call the interface method in the main activity?  @SanKoKo

Comment: Your `onBackPressed` and `onKeyDown` is out of `MainActivity` scope. Can you re-check the "}" at line 8.

Comment: Also try to add `alertDialog!!.cancelable = true` after `alertDialogBuilder.create()`

Comment: @NamNH onBackPressed and onKeyDown is in the main Activity scope that ways typo mistake (only here not in the actual program). By setting the alertDialog.setCancelable(true) will cause the dialog to disappear when user tap outside of the dialog. That will exactly not solved my problem.

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, i'm on my trip. You can add 2 lines  `alertDialog!!.setCancelable(true)` (this mean your dialog dismissed by Back Pressed) and `alertDialog!!.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` (with means your dialog is not dismissed when touch out side).

Comment: @NamNH I have added both the line. And thanks. Hope your trip was awesome.

Comment: Thanks, Hope that worked as your expected :)

Comment: Yes it works as expected. Can you have look at another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44606550/7124362. @NamNH

Answer (score 0):

You can show the dialog in your activity using the context in the adapter then check in the method onBackPressed if your dialog is visible then dismiss it else super.onBackPressed()

Comment: I tried this way but onBackPressed() is not calling after clicking on back button

Answer (score 0):

This must help.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I have override the onBackPressed() in the activity but when I am pressing the back button onBackPressed() is not calling.  @William